# Adding authenticated user ID information in server-side NodeJS Application Insights events

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a NodeJS app in which I'm consuming the `applicationinsights` NodeJS package ([this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights)). According to ApplicationInsights data model described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-data-model-context#anonymous-user-id), it says the property exists, but I am not able to find a code snipped as to how to set this property in the telemetry event I'm sending.

Any snipped describing how to do this would be helpful!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to your description, I only found the tutorials for ASP.NET about [Setting the user context in an ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-send-user-context) and [Authenticated users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#authenticated-users) for JavaScript.

Then I checked the `setAuthenticatedUserContext` method under [User.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/f07196947183f13703a507a636c197d72e4a91ba/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/Context/User.ts) of [Microsoft Application Insights SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS) and found the related code snippet under [TelemetryContext.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/0c1baa3ea806364ff0ab725b952bad84b9ca6a0a/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/TelemetryContext.ts) as follows:

```html
if (typeof userContext.authenticatedId === "string") {
      envelope.tags[tagKeys.userAuthUserId] = userContext.authenticatedId;
}
```

Then checked [ContextTagKeys.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK.Interfaces/Contracts/Generated/ContextTagKeys.ts) and found the context tags as follows:

```
this.sessionId = "ai.session.id";
this.userAccountId = "ai.user.accountId";
this.userId = "ai.user.id";
this.userAuthUserId = "ai.user.authUserId";
...
```

> but I am not able to find a code snipped as to how to set this property in the telemetry event I'm sending.

For NodeJS SDK, the context tag keys are under [ContextTagKeys.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/0131e35d29c268c8c99368a7a3a6435828186569/Declarations/Contracts/Generated/ContextTagKeys.ts). For your requirement, you could leverage the following code snippet:

```
appInsights.defaultClient.context.tags[appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.userAuthUserId] ="xxxx";
```

For [Session id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-data-model-context#session-id), [Account id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-data-model-context#account-id) or other context fields, you just need to choose the relevant context tag key.

Comment: With this you can set the Session/User ID once, right? But how do you set it up to use the sessionId and userId from the request so it's different for each request?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone is still struggling with adding user information to the telemetry event on a per-request basis, here's what I did:

```js
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");

appInsights.setup().start()
appInsights.defaultClient.addTelemetryProcessor(
  (envelope, context) => {
    // context keys from the `ContextTagKeys` contract
    const contextKeys = {
      userId: "userId",
      sessionId: "sessionId",
    }
    const getContextKey = (key) => {
      return appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys[key]
    }
    const setContextKey = (key, value) => {
      envelope.tags[key] = value;
    }

    // custom context that I set on per-request basis
    const requestContext = appInsights.getCorrelationContext().requestContext
    const data = envelope.data.baseData;

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(requestContext)) {
      switch (key) {
        case "userId":
          setContextKey(
            getContextKey("userId"),  // ai.user.id
            value                     // bob@example.com
          )
          break
        case "sessionId":
          setContextKey(
            getContextKey("userId"),  // ai.session.id
            value                     // 507f191e810c19729de860ea
          )
          break
        default:
          // if it's a custom property that doesn't belong in the
          // `ContextTagKeys` contract, such as browser information, add
          // it as a custom property on the `envelope.data.baseData` object
          data.properties[key] = value
      }
    }

    return true
  }
)
```

Then, since I am using `Express`, I created a middleware function that sets per-request information on the context object:

```js
const express = require('express')
const Bowser = require("bowser");

const app = express();

// ...

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const session = req.session;
  const userAgent = req.get('User-Agent')

  const sessionId = session.id
  const userId = session.userId
  const browser = Bowser.getParser(userAgent) 

  const currentRequestContext = 
    appInsights.getCorrelationContext().requestContext || {}

  const nextRequestContext = {
    ...currentRequestContext,
    sessionId,      // 507f191e810c19729de860ea 
    userId,         // bob@example.com
    browser:        // custom property, e.g. Firefox 83
      browser.getBrowserName() + " " + browser.getBrowserVersion()
  }

  appInsights.getCorrelationContext().requestContext = nextRequestContext

  next()
})
```

---

To get a list of all available `ContextTagKeys` contracts, have a look here:

- [ContextTagKeys.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/f843973866b6966e96ad884bca746a99930eec91/Declarations/Contracts/Generated/ContextTagKeys.ts#L129)
- [ContextTagKeys.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/ae71ebf806da82e149b0af60f00d70b2c1d3e3f0/shared/AppInsightsCommon/src/Interfaces/Contracts/Generated/ContextTagKeys.ts#L212) (client-side library)

  - It appears that some of these `ContextTagKeys` from the client-side library can be set in the server-side library as well, which is how I got the `client_Browser` property to show up in Azure portal after populating `ai.device.browserVersion` with browser information

Here's an example from the documentation on how to create your own custom telemetry processor:

- [Process data with Telemetry Processor](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js#preprocess-data-with-telemetry-processors)

Here are the issues on GitHub that helped me find the proper solution:

- [Support `setAuthenticatedUserContext` #356](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/356)
- [Per-request custom properties on auto-collected request #392](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/392)
- [Base type inside envelope always equals to request data. #713](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/713#issuecomment-742073525)

Lastly, here's the version of `applicationinsights` that I am using:

- `applicationinsights v1.8.8`